# Get amount of objects saved in MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to get amount of objects saved in MongoDB with

```
db = myclient.database_sample
my_collection = db["database"]


mydoc = my_collection.find().count()
print("The number of documents in collection : ", mydoc)
```

but I'm getting an error

```
mydoc = my_collection.find().count()
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I'm using Pymongo 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_find.asp) function for pymongo returns a cursor object (not an array). Pymongo does include a [count_documents function](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#counting). Meaning the code should look like this:

```
numberOfDocs = my_collection.count_documents({})
```

Edit: Updated to correct solution.

Comment: it's returning me an TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

Comment: Turns out find() returns a Cursor Object, not an array (which explains the 'Object of type "Cursor"' error. According to the documentation for pymongo, there is a count document function my_collection.find().count_documents({}). Will update the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep using .find() methods, you need to convert it to list:

```
numberOfDocs = len(list(my_collection.find()))
```